# Erlang simple "spawn" gets undefined error in windows

Tags: windows, erlang, erlang-shell

I'm learning Erlang and I've written a simple module to test "spawn" function:

```
-module(concurrent).
-export([go/0, loop/0]).
 
go() ->
    Pid2 = spawn(echo, loop, []).

loop() -> 2.
```

but when I run `concurrent:go().` I get this error message:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 10-Feb-2023::14:41:34.586000 === Error in process
<0.84.0> with exit value: {undef,[{echo,loop,[],[]}]}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to spawn a process running function `loop` from module `echo`. But you export function `loop` from module named `concurrent` and not `echo`.